Jetson pull docker images from gcloud Artifact Registry, Unauthenticated
So the problem is only with JETSON, I have problem with pulling docker images from Artifact Registry, it works on every ubuntu server, but not on jetson.
I have python v 3.8
Platform ARM
Steps I do
 # Install docker
  curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
  sudo sh get-docker.sh

# gcloud
  sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg curl sudo
  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
  curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install google-cloud-cli
  gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="./sa.json"

  gcloud auth configure-docker europe-docker.pkg.dev

If I do "gcloud auth list" I get the service account I have, I already set the account to OWNER and registry admin, if there could be GOD permission I would set it too.
I try to pull manually with this command
docker pull europe-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT/docker/cam-recorder-qa:277dacbdf2c5a105b7e86c771bccb4036e943198

No matter I do, I still have
Error response from daemon: Head "https://europe-docker.pkg.dev/v2/PROJECT/docker/cam-recorder-qa/manifests/277dacbdf2c5a105b7e86c771bccb4036e943198": denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" on resource "projects/PROJECT/locations/europe/repositories/docker" (or it may not exist)


I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

You can check the following possible solutions

You may  haven't configured the endpoint europe-docker.pkg.dev.  it's expected docker pulling an image in the region will fail. You need to run gcloud auth configure-docker europe-docker.pkg.dev to register this endpoint, and after which the pulls should succeed.

Possibly you may have missed the setup mentioned in this public documentation. Please verify if you missed any step.

Also verify that you  have these permissions not only at the org level, but at the project level as well. If you can confirm the service account has the permissions you listed at the Org level, but none of the permissions at the Project level, then the permissions must have been overridden.

If the images are private, you can check this document for pulling private images.

Finally, Refer Authenticating to a repository for more information


